# why is the result of boost::math::float_distance(1.0, 0.0) so big?

Tags: c++11, boost, precision

As the title mentioned, why is the result of boost::math::float_distance(1.0, 0.0), which is -4.60718e+18, so big?

According to this definition about ULP:
In general, if the floating-point number d.d...d × e is used to represent z, then it is in error by d.d...d - (z/e)p-1 units in the last place.
Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

The result shouldn't be such a big number, isn't it?

Comment: Could you post the code you're testing with, please?

Comment: I'm just a rookie to float point approximation and want to test the properties of boost::math::float_distance. The code is: int main() { std::cout << float_distance(1.0, 0.0) << std::endl; return 0}  @Ja_cpp

Comment: Can't find the dupe, right now, but if you multiply all the possible values representable by a 52 bit significand (in a IEEE754 64-bit double), which is 2^52 = 4.5E15 times 1023 (the difference between the exponents in the same representation), you get that number.

Comment: Thanks, @Bob__  ,I find it. It's the total distinct numbers of double between [0.0, 1.0], which is the difference between pow(2, 62) - pow(2, 52)